# Convert a number to letters

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Given a number, how do you convert that to letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just translate your existing logic into a t-sql scalar function, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnColumnNameFromIndex(@i int)
RETURNS varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dividend int, @letters varchar(3), @modulo int
    SET @dividend = @i
    SET @letters = ''

    WHILE @dividend > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @modulo = (@dividend - 1) % 26
        SET @letters = CHAR(65 + @modulo) + @letters
        SET @dividend = CONVERT(int, (@dividend - @modulo) / 26 )
    END

    RETURN @letters;
END
GO
```

Call it like this:

> SELECT dbo.fnColumnNameFromIndex(2000)

...admittedly not set logic, but I don't see this as a set logic problem.