# Adding a, b, c to end of data

Tags: t-sql

I have table with contract_code column, but in this column have same data, how can I change the same data to samedata_a, and samedata_b and etc.

For example:
Change this data

```
ASFRETERT
JDFJDSFJS
ASFRETERT
```

TO

```
ASFRETERT_a
JDFJDSFJS
ASFRETERT_b
```

Comment: Typically you would just give the column name an alias, but I am not sure that is what you are asking.  Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Add some Table Design Please..Little more explanations will be helpful to all

Comment: Really need more information than that @Fara..

Comment: I have table with contract_code column, but in this column have same data, i want change same data to samedata_a, samedata_b and etc.

Comment: @Fara please edit your original question and post some sample data.  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this by applying a `row_number()` to the column.  If you don't need the additional character to be an `alpha` character then it would be easier using the following:

The first version using CTE:

```
-- cte version
;with cte as
(
  select col1, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1) rn
  from yourtable
)
select 
  case when t1.cnt > 1 
      then c.col1 + '_' 
        + cast(c.rn as varchar(10))
      else c.col1
  end yourColumn
from cte c
inner join
(
  select count(*) cnt, col1
  from yourtable
  group by col1
) t1
  on c.col1 = t1.col1;
```

The second version uses sub-queries

```
-- non-cte version
select case when t2.cnt > 1 
      then t1.col1 + '_' 
          + cast(t1.rn as varchar(10))
      else t1.col1 
  end yourColumn
from 
(
  select col1, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1) rn
  from yourtable
) t1
inner join
(
  select count(*) cnt, col1
  from yourtable
  group by col1
) t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dc56/9).  The two versions above add an integer to the end of the column but if you want to apply an alpha character, you should add a function to your database (Code for function from this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676497/convert-a-number-to-letters)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnColumnNameFromIndex(@i int)
RETURNS varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dividend int, @letters varchar(3), @modulo int
    SET @dividend = @i
    SET @letters = ''

    WHILE @dividend > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @modulo = (@dividend - 1) % 26
        SET @letters = CHAR(65 + @modulo) + @letters
        SET @dividend = CONVERT(int, (@dividend - @modulo) / 26 )
    END

    RETURN @letters
END
```

If you create this function, then you can get the alpha character for each row.  Your queries would then be:

The CTE version:

```
-- cte version
;with cte as
(
  select col1, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1) rn
  from yourtable
)
select 
  case when t1.cnt > 1 
      then c.col1 + '_' 
        + cast(dbo.fnColumnNameFromIndex(c.rn) as varchar(10))
      else c.col1
  end yourColumn
from cte c
inner join
(
  select count(*) cnt, col1
  from yourtable
  group by col1
) t1
  on c.col1 = t1.col1;
```

The sub query version:

```
-- non-cte version
select case when t2.cnt > 1 
      then t1.col1 + '_' 
          + cast(dbo.fnColumnNameFromIndex(t1.rn) as varchar(10))
      else t1.col1 
  end yourColumn
from 
(
  select col1, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1) rn
  from yourtable
) t1
inner join
(
  select count(*) cnt, col1
  from yourtable
  group by col1
) t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1697a/11)

Comment: bluefeet thank you very match, for me is better second version non-cte

Comment: @Fara that is why I provided two versions, then you can decide the better route. :)