# How can I show the row_number alphabetically

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY setsid) AS Set_No,
       setsid,
       testid
FROM   examsets
WHERE  testid = 4
```

Result is :-

```
Set_No               
------------------- 
1                    
2                    
3                   
4                    
5                    
6                   
7
```

I want result As:-

```
Set_No               
------------------- 
a                    
b                    
c                   
d                    
e                    
f                   
g
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to show Alphabaticaly what?

Comment: You have shown the result you don't want. Please show the result you want-

Comment: And when you come to `z` what would be the next value?

Comment: there is nothing like being nuts.. If you cant do this just dont comment like this @rony

Comment: Same way you convert a number to a character.

Comment: @mikael requirement will be max to L so.. and if this case arise then can we done this like AA AB Ac.. Just for Knowledge..

Comment: you can use function to do the conversion like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676497/convert-a-number-to-letters

Comment: you can use case statement.or in table variable take col int and char(1)-- 1--a,2--b etc.then join this table variable with your set_no

Comment: buddy if i dont want to answer then i rather prefer not to comment... but why you want like this that the real concern...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this. It will not handle cases where you have more than 26 rows returned.

```
char(96+row_number() over(order by setsid))
```

Going from `AA` to `ZZ` will give you 676 different values.

```
select char(((T.N / 26) % 26) + 65) + char((T.N % 26) + 65) as Set_No
from (
     select row_number() over(order by setsid) - 1 as N
     from YourTable
     ) as T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13104)

Comment: @Gourav Yes, and you said you did not need to go further than `L`. I would very much like to suggest another solution for you but I don't really understand what you need this for.

Comment: Yes sir, I am thinking for the worst case if this condition arise... as of now our sets will not cross 10..

Comment: sounds like something that will turn bad at some point in time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      char(ascii(row_number() over (order by setsid))+48) as Set_No       
      setsid,
      testid
FROM   
      examsets
WHERE  
      testid = 4
```